# How to setup .env in Symfony for Reverse engineering using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, symfony4, reverse-engineering

I just started a project with Symfony 4.
In this project, I do not want to create my Entity but recover the existing database on an AS / 400.
According to the doc Symfony, I have to reverse engineer but I have to complete the `.env file` with the information from my database namely:
reverse_engineering

```
DATABASE_URL = mysql: // db_user: db_password@127.0.0.1: 3306 / db_name
```

However, the AS400 does not work with mysql but with DB2.

How can I make the bridge?

I'm thinking about using PDO, but I do not know how to make and modify my `.env file`.

Do you have an idea to help me?

Thanks for your help,
If you need more information, just let me know.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). It might be worth looking at https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.5/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/IBMDB2/DB2Driver.html which is a DB2 driver for Doctrine which Symfony uses.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I'll take a look :)

Comment: grammar and formatting